# Submitting pyspark supporting sql files inside zip file on AWS EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am looking to reference non-python files (e.g., SQL, config, txt) saved as .zip on S3 in my pyspark application on Amazon EMR. I have tried --py-files, but that only worked with my python files. I am still unable to use my zipped SQL/config files from S3 in Amazon EMR. Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag you are looking for `--archives`.  Basically you give it a zip file and it will extract it into the directory each yarn container is executing in.  You should be able to access them using relative paths in your script.

You can also control the name of the folder your zip is unzipped to by adding `#{name}` to the end.  For example `--archives s3://aaa/some.zip#files`.  Spark only mentions this in passing here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#important-notes

One thing to be aware of, if you are running your with `--deploy-mode client` then your driver is not running a yarn container, and therefore will not have access to the files.  You will instead want to use `--deploy-mode cluster`.

Comment: Thank you! I see that the .zip files are being added on cluster using --archives. I still am having trouble finding the relative paths where these files are in. If I am using this code sc.textFile("sql.zip/some_sql.sql") what would be the appropriate path here. Thanks again.

Comment: If you are going to load using `sc.textFile` then just leave them on S3 and load them from there.  --archives is useful if you want to load using python methods like `open`.  But, you are better off using the standard spark methods read methods and broadcasting if that works for your use case.

Comment: @RyanWidmaier can be this solution applied to this SF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619318/how-to-load-local-resource-from-a-python-package-loaded-in-aws-pyspark

Comment: Maybe, I'll comment over there.