# How to load local resource from a python package loaded in AWS PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I have uploaded a python package into AWS EMR with PySpark. My python package has a structure like the following, where I have a resource file (a sklearn joblib model) within the package:

```
myetllib
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── modules
    │   ├── bin
    │   ├── joblib
    │   ├── joblib-0.14.1.dist-info
    │   ├── numpy
    │   ├── numpy-1.18.4.dist-info
    │   ├── numpy.libs
    │   ├── scikit_learn-0.21.3.dist-info
    │   ├── scipy
    │   ├── scipy-1.4.1.dist-info
    │   └── sklearn
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── mysubmodule
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── model.py
        └── models/mymodel.joblib
```

I then zip the package and upload to EMR. Now I can import `model.py` in the console, doing like

```
from myetllib.mysubmodule.model import load_model, run_model
```

but when I call `load_model` I get an error that joblib complains not finding the package resource file, that is `models/mymodel.joblib`
The path is correctly set like

```
import joblib

BASE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
MODEL_PATH =  os.path.join(BASE_PATH,"models/my_model.joblib")

def load_model():
    '''
        load scikit-learn model via joblib
    '''
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)
        return joblib.load(MODEL_PATH)
```

and the error is like

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/mnt/tmp/spark-fc45e56b-06f3-56dd-af44-0ecc93d4gc0d/userFiles-1e3455-a6rf-4adc-592b-bbe41ffa323/etllib-v1.0.0.zip/etllib/mysubmodule/models/my_model.joblib
```

Also, I'm getting another error from `sklearn`:

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/mnt/tmp/spark-904b50d2-0407-43e8-bb46-06a7b334a46b/userFiles-5df387de-066e-498a-8dd3-e8329d0e8252/etllib-v1.0.1.zip/etllib/modules/sklearn/__check_build
```

Comment: Is it `model/my_model.joblib` or `models/my_model.joblib`.  Can you check the path pls?

Comment: Typo sorry, the path is correct. It is mysubmodule/models/my_model.joblib

Comment: `(BASE_PATH,"model/my_model.joblib")` is this `models/...`?

Comment: @Bala typo again, thank you. Now I get the same error for internal sklearn modules. Updating with the error.

Comment: When you say uploaded to EMR how exactly did you do that?  With `--py-files`?  Or maybe a bootstrap script?

Comment: @RyanWidmaier I actually use AWS Glue, so what happens is that the zip archive I upload to S3, is read directly without unzipping to a directory, but a temporary archive (see the path in the logs `/mnt/tmp/spark-...`.